# How can I pull two or more characters from a string?

Tags: java

I need to be able to enter an original number from 1-10000(let's say 1250) and input a number to divide it up (let's say 2) so that the program then separates the original by the number (so the answer would be 12, 25 50). How would I write the code to pull the numbers from the String into original.charAt(...)?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) { 
            System.out.println("Enter input:");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String original= input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter target:");
            int number= input.nextInt();
            // input.close();

            long output = 0;

            for (long k=0; k<=(original.length()-number); k++) {

                while (original.length)
```

//The code below this is basically my goal of what to accomplish
                    long value = original.charAt(h, (to) number+k);

Comment: how about using the substring method for String

Answer (score 1):

```
        int len = original.length();
        if(number <= 0 || number > len) {  // Checking for Invalid partition
            System.out.println("Invalid Partition");
        }
        else {
            String[] result = new String[len - number + 1];  
            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < len && index < result.length; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < number && i + j < len; ++j) {
                     result[index] = result[index] + original.charAt(i+j); // Appending character into partition 
                }
                index ++;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println(result[i]); // Printing all partition.
            }
        }
```

This will suffice your requirement. However you should yourself apply other constrains such as range of number. But instead of charAt() method, I would like to use substring method. More efficiently clean.

**Substring method**

```
        String[] result = new String[len - number + 1];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; index < result.length && i + number - 1  < len; ++i) {
            result[index] = original.substring(i, i + number);
            index ++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(result[i]);
        }
```

Comment: @RolandIllig yup my bad I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

To get all substrings of a given length, define this method:

```
public static List<String> substrings(String str, int len) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - len; i++) {
        result.add(str.substring(i, len));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code for this problem should not be any longer than this.

Except if you are programming in an environment where every nanosecond counts. These situations are very rare. In all other situations, writing clear code is more important than writing fast code.